# Define bijection between two sets $A\cup B$ and $A$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B,C$ be three sets such that $C \subset A$. $C$ and $B$ are two denumerable sets.  $A \cap B=\emptyset$. Then show that there exists bijection between $A$ and $A\cup B$.
as $C$ and $B$ are denumerable so there exists bijection between them. now we assign every element of $C$ to $B$. but how can I exhibit a bijection between $A\setminus C$ to $A$?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is countably infinite,  at the least:  $\lvert A\rvert\ge\lvert C\rvert$.  $B$ is countable.  Hence $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert  A\cup B\rvert $.   So there is a bijection between them.

Comment: why A is countably infinite?

Comment: @SwarnadeepBagchi it contains $C$.

Comment: why A is countably infinite?

Comment: we khow that if A is countably infinite then C is countably infinite but the converse is not necessarily true

Comment: as we know N is subset of R and N is countably infinite but R is uncountable

Comment: @SwarnadeepBagchi A set is at least as "big" as any subset of it .  You said $C$ is denumerable.  But $C\subset A$...  As i said,  $A$ is _at least_ countable...  perhaps larger...